# Why is zsh 5.7.1 different on linux and macos?

Tags: zsh

I want to build a portable `etc` repo which contains all my system config preferences. However zsh sources from `/etc/zshrc` on macos and from `/etc/zsh/zshrc` on linux. Why the heck is this different? It is exactly the same version (zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0) and zsh 5.7.1 (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)). Can I somehow bypass this problem?

Comment: What is `$ZDOTDIR` set to on those two systems?

Comment: Empty on both systems. If checking is as easy as `echo $ZDOTDIR`

Comment: Ok, then the next question would be to ask whether you are setting up `zsh` for yourself or for all users on the system, and why you are concerned about the exact location of the system-wide `zshrc` file.

Comment: `system config preferences` in `/etc` therefore for all users. I am concerned about the location because I want to have  a portable config. Meaning valid on macos and linux. Nevermind, I created a makefile with branches for installation.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because it's compiled differently. At least the Debian Zsh package compiles it with `--enable-etcdir=/etc/zsh`, to compartmentalize the files to a single directory, keeping the main `/etc` cleaner. Note that this may well about distribution-specific choices, not anything to do with Linux in general.

You can easily work around this by including in your repository symlinks from the files in `/etc/zsh` to their counterparts in `/etc` (or the other way around), or by symlinking the whole `/etc/zsh` to `.`.

Comment: Is there any way to query these compile-time options for `zsh`?